# how to kill a process windows in python with asking the process name in programme(script)

Tags: python, shell, kill

I want to write a Python script/program which kills a program specified by the user.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

I'm pretty new to Python and I just want a little script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach most likely is to write a thin wrapper around the [tasklist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) command. It does the following:

*"Displays a list of applications and services with their Process ID (PID) for all tasks running on either a local or a remote computer."*

So you would spawn a process (using Python's `subprocess` module) to run tasklist, fetch its output (stdout), and parse the output using standard Python methods. You would look for a certain program name in the output and then identify the corresponding process ID. You can then terminate the process using `os.kill()`.

Since you are a "noob in Python", you will probably spend quite some time learning the appropriate Python string manipulation/parsing functions, and also spend some time reading documentation about the subprocess module. All of this actually is quite simple, but you will have to invest some time -- believe me, this is worth the effort, you will learn a lot!